# What do i need to learn develop interactive web application not just websites?

Tags: web-applications

i have a good experience in desktop development using .net C# ,now i want to develop web application or simply i need to convert my desktop app to web app that can put on server and access it using browser form any PC on the same network but when i search for web development the courses,tutorials and books i have found always talk about build web sites and focus on build a blog or social website so i am confused i want to develop interactive web app with a lot of buttons,textbox,combobox,database access
which tools can help me in this i just hear about php,django for back end and html,css for front end but i am not sure how to start

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can definitely use django its a good python framework with both front-end and back-end functionality. its also support sqlite3 database for back-end and you also can change accordingly your needs like mysql, mongodb and postgressql.

other than django there is react and angular both are based on java script bot are front-end for back-end there is express and node both are based on java-script. both are good for making components for reusability of components. you can chose any one of them all are good at their place.
do reply if you have any doubt.